# DAX - Power BI - Creating Historical Table from Audit Table

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I'm trying to create a MonthEndStatus Historical table from the data in my Audit table. This table does not exist and we need to create it from the audit table records.

I have an Audit table that contains changes to Submission Records.

| SubID | RevID | Status | ChangeDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 1 | New | 1/2/2021 |
| 13 | 1 | New | 1/3/2021 |
| 12 | 2 | Open | 1/3/2021 |
| 13 | 2 | Open | 1/5/2021 |
| 12 | 3 | Closed | 4/1/2021 |
| 12 | 4 | Re-Open | 6/1/2021 |
| 12 | 5 | Closed | 9/2/2021 |
| 12 | 6 | Open | 9/3/2021 |
| 13 | 3 | Closed | 9/5/2021 |

I also have the standard date table with all the good Date data for each day.

I want the MonthEndStatus to look like

| SubID | Status | Month End |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | Open | 1/2021 |
| 13 | Open | 1/2021 |
| 12 | Open | 2/2021 |
| 13 | Open | 2/2021 |
| 12 | Open | 3/2021 |
| 13 | Open | 3/2021 |
| 12 | Closed | 4/2021 |
| 13 | Open | 4/2021 |
| 12 | Closed | 5/2021 |
| 13 | Open | 5/2021 |
| 12 | Re-Open | 6/2021 |
| 13 | Open | 6/2021 |
| 12 | Re-Open | 7/2021 |
| 13 | Open | 7/2021 |
| 12 | Re-Open | 8/2021 |
| 13 | Open | 8/2021 |
| 12 | Open | 9/2021 |
| 13 | Closed | 9/2021 |

My first thought was to use a Left Outer Merge from the Date table to the Audit table but it doesn't create a row for each ID for each Month.

How can I use Power BI DAX or other method to create the records for the months that are NOT in the Audit table and use the value from the previous month?

Thanks, in advance, for your assistance.

matt

Answer (score 0):

```
MonthEndStatus = 
    VAR EndOfMonthDates =
        TREATAS (
            SELECTCOLUMNS (
                ADDCOLUMNS (
                    VALUES ( Dates[MonthName] ),
                    "Date", CALCULATE ( MAX ( Dates[Date] ) )
                ),
                "Date", [Date]
            ),
            Dates[Date]
        )
RETURN
ADDCOLUMNS (
GENERATE ( VALUES ( Submissions[SubID] ), EndOfMonthDates ),
    "Status",
        VAR CurrentEndOfMonth = Dates[Date]
        VAR MAXSubbmissionDateInRange =
            CALCULATE (
                MAX ( Submissions[ChangeDate] ),
                REMOVEFILTERS ( Dates ),
                Submissions[ChangeDate] <= CurrentEndOfMonth
            )
        RETURN
            CALCULATE (
                SELECTEDVALUE ( Submissions[Status] ),
                REMOVEFILTERS ( Dates ),
                Submissions[ChangeDate] = MAXSubbmissionDateInRange
            )
)
```